# 'Want to save your changes?' message for Excel file opened via shortcut

Tags: microsoft-excel-2016

Recently, I've been getting a 'Want to save your changes?' message from  Excel 2016 when I close a certain file, even if the file hasn't been changed. The file is one that I use every day. I suspect that the problem may have arisen with a recent update of Excel: the program file was modified on 27 July 2017.

Because I use the file so frequently, I normally open it via a special shortcut:

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\EXCEL.EXE" "D:\finance\business\timesheet.xlsx"

If I open the file directly from within Excel, or by double clicking on it in File Explorer, the problem doesn't occur.

I can reproduce the problem using a very simple file, containing the numbers 1 to 5 in columns A and B, and a scatter chart of the points.

Comment: Not really an answer to your question, but perhaps a workaround: What happens if you create a shortcut to the .xlsx file directly?

Comment: Thanks. That does work, but I like to have my frequently used shortcuts pinned to the taskbar, which you can't do with a shortcut to a data file.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was fixed in version 1707 (Build 8326.2073), which was installed in an automatic update on 15 August 2017.

Comment: It would be good if you can cite a source such as a Microsoft Knowledge base article that says what was fixed.

Comment: I couldn't find any information about the problem - I'm just going by my own tests. (I hoped that someone would verify the original problem, but that didn't happen.)

Comment: My current version is 1707 (Build 8326.2073). Updates are listed at https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Update-history-for-Office-Insider-for-Windows-desktop-64bbb317-972a-4933-8b82-cc866f0b067c#InsiderLevel=Office_Insider_Slow. I suspect that the fix of this bug, which evidently arose in a fairly recent update, is included under "minor fixes and improvements".

Comment: It would be worth at least editing your answer to state "seems to be fixed as of version X, build ... " As then people with the same problem can check which version they have and update if necessary. Granted most people should automatically update, but some may not. It's a pity their changelogs are not particularly comprehensive, though it can be difficult to be with such a large product.